# family of torsors and family of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are smooth connected schemes over a field $k=\bar{k}$, $f: X\times_kY\to X$ is the first projection. You may assume $Y$ is proper if you like, my question is if $P\to X\times_kY$ is a $G$-torsor with $G$ finite group scheme over $k$ then can we say that the fibres of $P$ under $f$ are "constant". More precisely is there a functorial (with respect to $P$) isomorphism between $P_s$ and $P_{s'}$ for $s,s'$ any two rational points in $X$.

The similar question is that if $V$ is a vector bundle on $X\times_kY$ and if the fibres of $V$ along closed points of $X$ are all trivial vector bundles on $Y$, then do we have (in a functorial way) a vector bundle $W$ on $X$ such that $f^*W\cong V$ ?

The answer to the sencond problem is yes if we assume $Y$ is proper, this is a very standard algebraic geometry argument: using Grauert's base change theorem one can show that $f^*f_*V\to V$ is always an isomorphism.  But what happens when $Y$ is not proper? do we have counter examples?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question $1$ is no even with $Y$ trivial. If we had a functorial isomorphism between the fibers on any two rational points in $X$, the torsor would be trivial, and there would be no reason to expect that.

$f_*V$ is a  locally free sheaf of $\mathcal O(X) \times \Gamma(Y,\mathcal O(Y))$ modules. You can take an open cover of $X$ and look at the transition matrices, then just ignore the $\Gamma(Y,\mathcal O(Y))$ part. This gives you a vector bundle. Then you can just trivialize the $\Gamma(Y,\mathcal O(Y))$ part since its automorphism group is a constant sheaf. This tells you how to glue the pullback of that vector bundle to $V$.

This doesn't appear to be normalized, so it should be defined up to the action of $GL_n(\Gamma(Y,\mathcal O(Y)))$. But that's not too bad.

Comment: Why if $Y$ is trivial and if there is a functorial isomorphism between the fibres for two rational points implies the torsor is trivial? I could not see it. But if we fix two rational points $x,x'\in X$, and if $Y$ is trivial, then there is a functorial isomorphism between the fibres if we take the ambient category to be the category of torsors $P\to X$ with two fixed $k$-rational points $p,p'\in P$ lying above $x,x'$ respectively.

Comment: By "any two" I meant "every two". We also have to require the isomorphism to be algebraically definable, and thus continuous. Then locally it must agree with the local trivialization of $P$ so the local trivialization of $P$ must be functorial which means $P$ is trivial.

I guess the real categorical setting you want to think about is the fundamental groupoid of the space. In topology we would get a functor from the fundamental groupoid to the category of fibers of the torsor. But I don't think you can define the fundamental groupoid algebraically.

Comment: I think the fundamental groupoid has an algebraic definition in terms of fiber functors on the finite étale site.

Comment: @Will Sawin: I just want to say that the assumptions that $Y$ is connected and locally of finite type are very important here. Take two extreme examples: 1) $Y$ is a non-trivial field extension of $k$, then all the fibres are certainly trivial but a vector bundle on the product can not be descent to $X$ in general; 2) $Y$ is a disjoint union of Spec($k$) (say two pieces), then $X\times Y$ is just a disjoit union of $X$. if I take two defferent vector bundles on X and put them together on $X\times Y$ then this vector bundle is not from $X$ while the fibres are obviously trivial.

Comment: I think my argument might actually fail entirely then. Since there's no indication that it doesn't work on those cases.

In fact, my argument depends on the statement $GL_n(R_1 \times R_2)=\GL_n(R_1) \times GL_n(R_2)$. This is true for the Cartesian product, and thus should usually be false for the tensor product, and in particularly not functorial.

Let $X$ be a curve and let $Y$ be a subvariety of its Jacobian. Is it obvious that the line bundle on $X \times Y$ induced by the map of $Y$ into the Jacobian nontrivial on the fibers?

Comment: I think the key point here is that the topology of the Cartesian product of two schemes is not the product topology of the two schemes. The open sets of the form $U\times V$ (with $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ open) do not form a topological basis for the topology of $X\times Y$. For example, if $K$ is a non-trivial field extension of $k$, then $K\times_kK$ clearly does not carry the product topology. Therefore you can not trivialize the bundle by some open in $X$.

Comment: I don't think that's the only obstruction, since you can consider some of the counterexamples in complex analysis or topology.

Comment: Also some of your examples are proper. I think you need connected, and maybe some other conditions, for it to work.

Comment: only the second counter example is proper, the properness works only under the condition that $Y$ is connected and separable over $k$, the real good thing in this case is that $f_*O_{X\times Y}=O_X$ holds universally. 